# Writing a query using orelse (OR) in chicagoboss

Tags: mongodb, erlang, chicagoboss

I looked for this query in Chicagoboss API, but could not find any solution to write a "OR" query. I have to write a query something like:

```
select * from TableName where  table.key1 = "XXXX1" OR   table.key2 = "XXXX2"
```

Here is my chicagoboss query, I want to check if any of the three flags is true then do something with heirs.

```
Heirs = boss_db:find(heir, [{flag1, 'equals', true}, {flag2, 'equals', true},
                            {flag3, 'equals', true}], [{order_by, code}]).
```

To execute this, Is there something like:

```
Heirs = boss_db:find(heir, [{{flag1, 'equals', true}, orelse, {flag2, 'equals', true}, orelse, {flag3, 'equals', true}}], [{order_by, code}]).
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](http://chicagoboss.org/api-db.html) and the source code of [boss_db.erl](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/boss_db/blob/2efb9417fdc3a5ceb9f362d3adbef2d7df3867b4/src/boss_db.erl), `find/3` seems to return records matching **all** of the given conditions.

You should file [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/boss_db/issues).

A workaround exists for SQL databases (use undocumented function `boss_db:find_by_sql/3`), but none for MongoDB which you seem to use because of the tag. So you will have to fetch the records through several calls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have raised and issue https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/boss_db/issues/185.

Comment: However let us wait, if someone would like to comment something more. Will accept your answer in two days. Don't mind bro.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some like this:

```
Var = case boss_db:find(heir,[{flag1, 'equals', true}]) of 
        Data -> Data;
        [] -> case boss_db:find(heir,[{flag2, 'equals', true}]) of 
                   Data -> Data;
                   [] -> "no data" 
              end 
      end.
```